# External site authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-scraping

I have requirements to build a site with authentication a bit like OpenId but instead of using Facebook or Google creds, I need to authenticate the user with their credentials from a system maintained by our software vendor. Unfortunately they do not offer any api (at all) and they don't have the expertise to build one. Since the situation is a bit desperate my solution is to have a regular login page, after the user puts in their creds I perform a http post to the vendors login page e.g:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["username"] = "myUser";
    data["password"] = "myPassword";

var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```

Then I will scrape the userId from the landing page. And thus authenticating the user. 
I guess what I am asking is a sanity check, would this method be too insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you send user data as plain text. You have to use SSL otherwise users will compromised sooner or later.